# Stabilizability, what does it mean to steer to zero

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-theory

The definition of stabilizability for linear systems is:

> Stabilizability is the ability to steer a system to zero, with a control input that can be defined over an infinite amount of time.

This is for continuous-time systems and discrete-time systems.
But what exactly does this mean? Why zero? Can someone explain this a bit more in easy language?

Comment: There are different definitions of stabilizability. They differ depending on systems under consideration (linear / non-linear), types of contol allowed and problems being solved. Without further clarification, the question is too broad.

Comment: Note also that for linear systems zero is always an equilibrium point.